# installing mysql-server on ubuntu 10.04

Tags: mysql, linux, ubuntu

I've had this same issue EVERY time I try:

```
Selecting previously deselected package mysql-server-core-5.1.  
(Reading database ... 242369 files and directories currently installed.)  
Unpacking mysql-server-core-5.1 (from .../mysql-server-core-5.1_5.1.41-  3ubuntu12.10_i386.deb) ...  
Selecting previously deselected package mysql-server-5.1.  
Unpacking mysql-server-5.1 (from .../mysql-server-5.1_5.1.41-3ubuntu12.10_i386.deb) ...  
Selecting previously deselected package libhtml-template-perl.  
Unpacking libhtml-template-perl (from .../libhtml-template-perl_2.9-1_all.deb) ...  
Selecting previously deselected package mysql-server.  
Unpacking mysql-server (from .../mysql-server_5.1.41-3ubuntu12.10_all.deb) ...  
Processing triggers for man-db ...  
Processing triggers for ureadahead ...  
ureadahead will be reprofiled on next reboot  
Setting up mysql-server-core-5.1 (5.1.41-3ubuntu12.10) ...  
Setting up mysql-server-5.1 (5.1.41-3ubuntu12.10) ...
```

And it just hangs there. This time I left it overnight, 12 hours later it's still there.

What am I missing?

Comment: Did you get a download from mysql web site or installing from synaptic?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like it might be failing when it should be prompting you for a mysql root password. Try

```
export DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive
apt-get -q -y install mysql-server-5.1
```

Then set the mysql root password afterwards by using

```
mysqladmin -u root password NEWPASSWORD
```

Answer (score 0):

ONe post which I encountered touched on the mysql installation is

http://onaxer.com/blog/blog/2011/03/08/install-mysql-5-5-on-ubuntu/